# Getting TypeError when trying to read the individual values in an Image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, typeerror

```
im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(1367, 845, 1485,863))
im.save(f'im_4_' + str(int(time.time())) + '.png', 'PNG')

y = Image.Image.getcolors(im)
z = len(Image.Image.getcolors(im))
```

Trying to use `len()` function to get my loop going.
The code above runs some times and then other times it gives me the following error, makes no sense to this beginner.  `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`.

Comment: Try using `im.getcolors()` because [`getcolors()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getcolors) is an `Image` object method. I agree the documentation is a little confusing in this regard.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance Martineau!!!  I did implement it, but still getting a type error on then len() line.  Any more thoughts?

Comment: Martineau, based on your last comments, I went back and reread and caught link which was also very helpful.  switched to getdata() haven't had error since,  Many thanks,

Comment: Donny: You're missing my point — which is that the answer I posted below to _this_ question, answers it, and should be accepted because it does, even if you're now doing something else for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

There's one — potentially two — problems with your code, the main one is that you're not calling the [`getcolors()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getcolors) method properly. Since it's a method of `Image` objects, it should be called on an *instance* of one, so in your case that would be  like this:

```
im.getcolors()
```

Secondly, that above may not be good enough because — if you read the documentation closely — `getcolors()` also accepts an optional `maxcolors` parameter and the docs say:

> **maxcolors** – Maximum number of colors. If this number is exceeded, this method returns `None`. The default limit is 256 colors.

Note the part about it returnng `None` when there's more colors than the default limit.

Off-topic: You can save the file with this line:

```
im.save(f'im_4_{int(time.time())}.png')
```

which makes slightly more succinct use of the f-string functionality Python has plus takes advantage of the fact you don't need to explictly supply the `PNG` image type because you put a `.png` extension on the filename.